# jquery infinite scroll returns duplicate rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using Jquery Infinite scrolldown, everything is fine but it returns duplicate rows if you scroll down constantly. I think I need some kind of a delay or do you have any suggestions?

here is the jquery code...

```
function sendData() {
                //*****************************************
                // THIS RETURNS THE LAST ID OF DIV*********
                // ****************************************
                counter = $("div.div_product_id:last").attr('id'); 
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "insaat.aspx/GetData",
                        data: "{'number_of_rows':'" + counter + "','cat':'" + _cat + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: "true",
                        cache: "false",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $("#myDiv").append(msg.d);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

How can I prevent to return duplicate row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, put the URL of the plugin you are using.

Comment: The response is correct? There are unique ids in it? Test ir with firebug.